# Button inside an item listview that on click it shows me a Context Menu

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview

As you can read, I have a problem about doing a button that on click of an item in a ListView shows me a context menù. I tried a lot of tutorials about it, but I wanted to try this thing and I didn't work:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            registerForContextMenu(button);
            openContextMenu(button);
        }
    });
```

but it crashes.. instead of it I used also doing without a button but that on press the item ListView it appears the context menu and it works and I did something like that

```
registerForContextMenu(listView_songs);
```

and then I have this code :

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuset, menu);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Set as");

}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.as_ringtone){
        Toast.makeText(this, "TryRingtone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.as_notify){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Try Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

someone can help me to find a way to put a button inside of every Item ListView and showing me the context menu? I want to obtain something like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSgq7.png)

Thanks..

Comment: It's better for you to work with recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is recommended to use RecyclerView instead of ListView. It is more customizeable.
Secondly, it is called popup menu or overflow menu. You can find more information on this [link](https://youtu.be/s1fW7CpiB9c)

Hope it helps, let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Dude, first of all thank you for your precious time. But I've got an issue.. I tried to build the popup menu as you said but I've got this error: https://ibb.co/nnmtJWW